# Visual studio 2017 - group members list by class (in the hierarchy)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way, through the options or an extension, to group the list members by class ? Let's say I have the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public void Method1A()
    {}

    public void Method2A()
    {}
}

public class B : A
{
    public void Method1B()
    {}
}

public class C : B
{
    public void Method1C()
    {}

    public void Method2C()
    {}

    public void Method3C()
    {}
}
```

So when I have this code

```
var c = new C();    
c. // <-- triggers list members dropdown
```

I want it to show (grouped by class)

```
C -----------
Method1C()
Method2C()
Method3C()
B -----------
Method1B()
A -----------
Method1A()
Method2A()
```

Instead of (all members sorted alphabetically)

```
Method1A()
Method1B()
Method1C()
Method2A()
Method2C()
Method3C()
```

I program for the Unity3D Game Engine and it's extremely annoying to try to find that single member of my custom component that is occluded with the ton of members inherited from MonoBehaviour.

It would be more productive for other custom classes as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure of an extension, but you could work around it..a bit dirty with interfaces. So instead of referencing the class you reference an interface that only has your methods

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't really feel like my design should depend on a workaround to achieve this, also, it may not be possible for all scenarios.